# installing nginx-module-njs with existing install nginx on ubi8

Tags: nginx, ubi

Has anyone been successful in install `nginx-module-njs` on `ubi8` ?

I created this issue https://github.com/nginx/njs/issues/652

```
nginx -v
nginx/1.20.1

yum install nginx-module-njs-1.20.1*


Last metadata expiration check: 0:03:33 ago on Wed Jun 14 17:32:47 2023.
Error:
 Problem: problem with installed package nginx-mod-http-perl-1:1.20.1-1.module+el8.6.0+13722+f063ea60.x86_64
  - package nginx-mod-http-perl-1:1.20.1-1.module+el8.6.0+13722+f063ea60.x86_64 requires nginx(abi) = 1.20.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package nginx-mod-http-perl-1:1.20.1-1.module+el8.6.0+791+48a2bb9d.x86_64 requires nginx(abi) = 1.20.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install both nginx-1:1.20.1-1.el8.ngx.x86_64 and nginx-1:1.20.1-1.module+el8.6.0+13722+f063ea60.x86_64
  - cannot install both nginx-1:1.20.1-1.el8.ngx.x86_64 and nginx-1:1.20.1-1.module+el8.6.0+791+48a2bb9d.x86_64
  - package nginx-module-njs-1:1.20.1+0.7.0-1.el8.ngx.x86_64 requires nginx-r1.20.1, but none of the providers can be installed
  - cannot install the best candidate for the job
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)
```

but theses errors

```
yum module list nginx-module-njs
Error: No matching Modules to list
```